# Coding factors with non-numeric settings

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, categorical-data, experiment-design

For my role as a TA I am assisting the instructor in developing curriculum based on DOE and statistics.

We have a set of failure strengths (the output/dependent variable) for several glass rods. The independent variables are diameter and surface finish. While there is numeric information for the diameter, the surface finish is marked as A for abraded and S for smooth. While this could be coded as -1 and +1, I have no idea how to interpret the coefficients of the model once a linear regression has been performed.

How can we code the data and subsequently use the model as a predictive tool?

Comment: Are diameter and surface finish really dependent variables or are they rather the input/independent variables?

Comment: Faulkner - I took the liberty of editing to make the second "dependent" to read "independent" (and fixed another typo while there). Please check that it says what you intend.

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of ways to validly code the "surface finish" variable. The most common way would be to code them as 0 and 1. That way the coefficient in a main effects model (strength ~ diameter + finish) would estimate the average difference in strength for the two finishes, given the same diameter. The one coded as 0 would be the "baseline" category. The coefficient for the 0-1 dummy in the regression would represent the shift from the baseline mean to get the other mean.

If you code as (-1,1), then the coefficient represents an estimate of *half* the difference in population means (and the meaning of the intercept also changes).

To use in predictions, it doesn't matter how you code; you just multiply the coefficient by the coding you used.

I'll see if I can mock up an example. If you have a small sample data set (say a dozen observations) I could use that.

Okay, here's a small example (not only the data but also the units are made up):

```
strength diameter finish
32.13075       17      A
40.15048       16      S
20.10630       12      A
26.13942       15      A
59.98352       14      A
25.92413       13      A
79.81273       14      S
70.15717       24      A
56.01118       20      A
22.08519        7      S
93.19808       24      S
91.86548       24      A
34.09182       13      A
83.82144       18      S
40.19491       17      S
66.01798       22      S
46.06970       19      A
51.92729       20      A
19.97026       15      A
56.13245       18      A
54.15978       15      S
28.03752       12      A
75.99303       18      S
 2.13246        4      A
25.98175       14      A
```

Now if we code a dummy "finish.S" as A=0, S=1 
then the model can be with IVs `diameter` and `finish.S`

We can then fit a regression:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -19.2460     9.9774  -1.929  0.06674  
diameter      3.7583     0.5885   6.387    2e-06 
finish.S     17.9057     5.8642   3.053  0.00583 

Residual standard error: 14.02 on 22 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7109,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6846 
F-statistic: 27.04 on 2 and 22 DF,  p-value: 1.181e-06
```

The fitted equation is

```
strength = -19.25 + 3.7583 diameter + 17.91 finish.S
```

where finish.S = 1 if finish="S" and is 0 otherwise.

Here's a plot of the two fitted lines:

[image]

on the other hand, if you coded as A=-1 and S=1:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -10.2932    10.0415  -1.025  0.31647 
diameter      3.7583     0.5885   6.387    2e-06 
finish.1      8.9528     2.9321   3.053  0.00583 

Residual standard error: 14.02 on 22 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7109,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6846 
F-statistic: 27.04 on 2 and 22 DF,  p-value: 1.181e-06
```

The fitted equation is

```
strength = -10.29 + 3.7583 diameter + 8.95 finish.1
```

where finish.1 either has the value 1 or -1.

So the line for "A":

```
strength = (-10.29 - 8.95)   + 3.7583 diameter
```

and the line for "S":

```
strength = (-10.29 + 8.95) + 3.7583 diameter
```

My rounding error aside, you end up with the same two fitted lines (the same predictions) with either coding.